# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "--Array functions---";
?></br>
<?php
$numbers = [
    5   , 
    4, 
    2, 
    7,
    8, 
    'name' => [
        'jimit',
        'prashant',
        'neel'
    ]
];

foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
    echo implode(" ", $value);
}
```

i got array message Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed 
any solution for this please suggest me

Comment: Only your last element in `$numbers` is an array. And `implode()` needs an array as second argument.

Comment: `$value` is an array only in the last case. Otherwise it's number. `implode` wants array, not a number.

Comment: only print name values how can i

Comment: you dont want to print the whole array along with the numbers. you only want to print the names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions according to your question & your posted comments:

When you want to print only the names of the 'name' key element, then place this code:

```
$arr = array();
 foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $val){
            if($key == 'name') {
                $arr[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}  
echo implode(" ", $arr);
```

OR

If you want to print the whole array along with the numbers, then place this code:

```
$arr = array();
  foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $val){
                $arr[] = $val;
            }
        } else {
            $arr[] = $value;
        }
    }
    echo $result = implode(" ", $arr);
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `$value` is not an array.

check before impolde.

```
foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        echo implode(" ", $value);
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```